# How can setting timeout value of Npgsql?

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

I using `CommandTimeout=5` to setting timeout, but it is not ok.

This is my code:

```
Dim con As New NpgsqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New NpgsqlCommand
        Dim conStr As String
        Try
            Dim sql = "Select * from dat_extract_text a join dat_replace_text b on a.tm_id=b.tm_id 
join dat_base_text_dt c on c.tm_id=a.tm_id
join dat_base_text_dt_font d on d.tm_id=c.tm_id
limit 250000"
            conStr = "Server=192.168.1.10;Port=5434;UserId=testuser;Password=1234;Database=testdb;CommandTimeout=5;"
            con.ConnectionString = conStr
            con.Open()

            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = sql

            Dim st = DateTime.Now
            Dim rs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
            Dim et = DateTime.Now
            Dim t = (et - st).TotalSeconds           
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Time of my query is about 40s, but it not occur timeout.

How can setting timeout value of Npgsql?

Comment: How is it not OK? Does it time out before the query completes? Is it taking too long?

Comment: I set CommandTimeout is 5s, but query not occur error time out.

Answer (score 3):

Let us get your code straightened out a bit.

Connections and commands need to be closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks take care of this for you.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor. Likewise the command text and connection can be passed to the constructor of the command.

If you want to time something use the Stopwatch class available in .net.

A Select statement is not a NonQuery. It will return a result set. Using a DataTable will allow you to use the data.

An empty Catch is of no help because it just swallows errors an you don't know what has gone wrong.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim sql = "Select * from dat_extract_text a join dat_replace_text b on a.tm_id=b.tm_id 
                join dat_base_text_dt c on c.tm_id=a.tm_id
                join dat_base_text_dt_font d on d.tm_id=c.tm_id
                limit 250000"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New NpgsqlConnection("Server=192.168.1.10;Port=5434;UserId=testuser;Password=1234;Database=testdb;"),
        cmd As New NpgsqlCommand(sql, con)
        'cmd.CommandTimeout = 5
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Test the code this way, without the timeout and without the Try...Catch to see what line the error occurs on and what the error is.

Comment: I used your code, and open cmd.CommandTimeout = 5, but it not stop my query. it still load data after 34s. i want, if my query after 5s can't return , it has to stop and occur timeout.

Comment: @DT I see there were some problems with .CommandTimeout with EF6 and it is ignored with Async. Neither of these are the problem. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server  This may help.

Comment: I have to setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 3):

Use Timeout instead of CommandTimeout.
Refer this - https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html

```
conStr = "Server=192.168.1.10;Port=5434;UserId=testuser;Password=1234;Database=testdb;Timeout=5;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that particular provider but, like other ADO.NET providers, the command object, i.e. the `NpgsqlCommand` instance, has a `CommandTimeout` property. You should presumably be setting that.

Comment: i had try : cmd.CommandTimeout = 5, but it is not working.